# Custom PropertyGridEditor etc. for web part edit zone?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-parts

I want to change the appearance of the default editor parts, and am a little unsure of how to go about doing this, as there seems to be a surprising lack of documentation on the subject.

I've been able to create a custom declarative catalog with some trial and error and overriding the RenderCatalogPart method, and now wish to do something similar with my AppearanceEditor and PropertyGridEditor.  I've tried just changing the style of the editor parts using CSS, but they are already arranged into tables which are impossible to get rid of.  It's not even possible to just take the class as is, because the classes are sealed.  So I'm basically stuck with having to write my own from scratch, I guess the questions are as follows:

1) How do I go about getting the information on the controls I need to render?

2) According to the documentation, I need to override the ApplyChagnes and SyncChanges methods - but I can't find any information on what I actually need to put in these methods.

3) On a similar note, is it possible to change the layout of the EditorPart itself, so that the AppearanceEditor, BehaviourEditor etc. are displayed side-by-side instead of on top of eachother?

4) Is there any way to have the page catalog displayed somewhere on the page, even in browse mode?  I'd quite like to use it as a 'minimised' area, where users can send web parts they don't want immediately.  At the moment they go back into the page catalog and users tend to just add a new part instead.  I know that I can have multiple catalog zones on the page, which is great, but it only shows up in catalog mode.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get any replies here, but I was able to figure out a way to do some of these.

1. In the end I decided to use reflection to get each public property on the web part that was WebBrowsable, and figure out what sort of control to display from the type.
2. The ApplyChanges() and SyncChanges() methods essentially just persist the changes from the page to the personalization blob and vice-versa.  It's a matter of rendering some controls on the page, and mapping the values to the properties of the web part in these methods.
3. I don't think this is possible without writing your own.
4. Haven't been able to do this, but I don't imagine that it's possible sadly.

Comment: Congrats on the fix.  When you are able, be sure to accept your answer so that other can learn from your solution.  Cheers~