# Add Custom Property in WebPart Editor Zone

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-parts, editor-zone

- I have webparts which display the content.
- Using Webpart Editor zone I need to select display style.
- By Selecting the Style i need the data to be displayed either in Grid or List or Rolling (from Dropdownlist).
- How can i add custom property in Webpart Editor Zone.

I'm newbie to this.

I have Google'd about this but got nothing.

Any help is Appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

As [Mathew Collins writes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007948/custom-propertygrideditor-etc-for-web-part-edit-zone/8066635#8066635):

> I didn't get any replies here, but I was able to figure out a way to
>   do some of these.
>
> 1. In the end I decided to overirde the EditorPart class.
> 2. The ApplyChanges() and SyncChanges() methods essentially just persist the changes from the page to the personalization blob and
>      vice-versa.  It's a matter of rendering some controls on the page, and
>      mapping the values to the properties of the web part in these methods.

Like

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts
Imports System.Data
Imports FormsUtilities

Namespace CustomEditorZone

    Public Class CustomEditor : Inherits EditorPart

        Public Sub New()
            Me.Title = "Change Display Style"
        End Sub 'New

        Private PartPropertyValue As DropDownList

        Protected Overrides Sub CreateChildControls()
            Controls.Clear()
            PartPropertyValue = New DropDownList()
            PartPropertyValue.AppendDataBoundItems = True
            PartPropertyValue.Items.Add("")
            PopulateControl(PartPropertyValue)
            Me.Controls.Add(PartPropertyValue)
        End Sub 'CreateChildControls

        Public Overrides Function ApplyChanges() As Boolean

            EnsureChildControls()
            Dim MyWebPart As GenericWebPart = DirectCast(WebPartToEdit, GenericWebPart)
            Dim MyControl As CustomWebPart.WebPartBaseConsumer = DirectCast(MyWebPart.ChildControl, CustomWebPart.WebPartBaseConsumer)
            MyControl.DisplayStyle = PartPropertyValue.SelectedItem.Text
            Return True

        End Function 'ApplyChanges

        Public Overrides Sub SyncChanges()
            Try
                EnsureChildControls()
                Dim MyWebPart As GenericWebPart = DirectCast(WebPartToEdit, GenericWebPart)
                Dim MyControl As CustomWebPart.WebPartBaseConsumer = DirectCast(MyWebPart.ChildControl, CustomWebPart.WebPartBaseConsumer)
                Dim CurrentDisplay As String = MyControl.DisplayStyle

                For Each Item As ListItem In PartPropertyValue.Items
                    If Item.Text = CurrentDisplay Then
                        Item.Selected = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try

        End Sub 'SyncChanges

        Protected Overrides Sub RenderContents(ByVal writer As HtmlTextWriter)
            Try
                writer.Write("Display Style :")
                writer.Write("&nbsp;")
                Me.PartPropertyValue.RenderControl(writer)
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try

        End Sub 'RenderContents

        Private Sub PopulateControl(ByRef PartPropertyValue As DropDownList)

            PartPropertyValue.Items.Add("Grid")
            PartPropertyValue.Items.Add("List")
            PartPropertyValue.Items.Add("Rolling")
        End Sub

    End Class 'CustomEditor
End Namespace
```